# How to calculate the functional derivative of the functional integral?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, path-integral, functional-derivatives

I study by myself with the QFT, in the page 197 of book of Lewis H. Ryder (2nd edition), The author wrote that he take the functional derivative of equation 6.69:

$$\frac {\delta\widehat{Z}[\phi]}{\delta\phi}$$

where $$\widehat {Z}[\phi]=\frac{{e}^{iS}}{\int{{e}^{iS}}{\cal D}\phi}\tag{6.69}$$

and

$$S=-\int{\left[\frac {1}{2} \phi(\Box+{m }^{ 2 })\phi -{\cal L  }_{ int } \right] { d }^{ 4 }x }.\tag{6.71} $$

The result in Eq. 6.72 is:

$$\frac { \delta  }{ \delta \phi  } \left\{ \exp\left[ -i\int { \left[ \frac { 1 }{ 2 } \phi (\Box +{ m }^{ 2 })\phi-{\cal L}_{ int } \right]  } { d }^{ 4 }x \right]  \right\} { \left[ \int { \exp\left[ iS \right]  } {\cal D}\phi  \right]  }^{ -1 }\\=
\left( \Box +{ m }^{ 2 } \right) \phi \widehat { Z } [\phi ]-\frac { \partial { \cal L }_{ int } }{ \partial \phi  }\widehat { Z } [\phi ].\tag{6.72} $$

I don't understand how the calculating procedure taking place. I have known how to calculate the functional derivative to a functional, **but I do not know how to take it to a functional integral like $\widehat{Z}[\phi]$**. I would be most thankful if anyone help me.

PS: Is there are some detailed textbook or literature about this technique?

Comment: Just like you take any other derivative. But watch out that the denominator (the actual functional integral) does not depend on $\phi$, as it is being integrated over there, so you only have to derive the action in the numerator.

Comment: The denominator is just a normalisation constant *independent* of $\phi$. So the derivative acts only on the numerator and the result is just $\hat{Z}' = iS' \hat{Z}$ as claimed (with the Factor $i$ missing).

Comment: Oh, god!thanks! please keeping online, I immediately take a calculation.And I also have some questions about functional derivative involving functional integral

Comment: I take a calculation just now,I found:$\frac{\delta}{ \delta\phi}\frac{1}{C}{e}^{iS}=\frac{1}{C}\frac{ \partial}{\partial\phi}{e}^{iS}=\frac{1}{C}{e}^{iS }i\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}S\left[\phi\right]$ with $C$ is denomenator,the derivative $\frac {\partial}{\partial\phi}S\left[\phi  \right]$ involving a integral of dx, why the result in Lewish. Ryder's book is lacking this integral?

Comment: Functional differentiation "kills" space-time integrals: If you write the variation of the action as $\delta S = \int d^4 x \, S'[\phi] \, \delta \phi(x)$, then $S'[\phi] = \delta S/\delta \phi$ is precisely the functional derivative of the action $S$.

Comment: Thanks @Tom Heinzl,I also try to understand the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}S\left[\phi\right]$ always a functional derivative respect to $\phi$, so I get:$\frac{\partial S}{\partial\phi}=-\left[\frac{ \partial}{\partial\phi}\frac{1}{2}\phi(\Box+{m}^{2})\phi-\frac{\partial{L}_{int}}{\partial\phi}  \right] =-\left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial\phi} \frac{1}{2}(\Box+{m}^{2})\phi-\frac{\partial{L}_{int} }{\partial\phi}\right]$, there always a coefficient $\frac{1}{2}$ ,why it is't appearance Ryder's result

Comment: You've got two $\phi$'s, so by the chain rule you get a factor 2 cancelling the 1/2. I'm normally using an inner product notation for the free action, like $S_0 = -(\phi, K \phi)/2$ where $K = \Box + m^2$ is the Klein-Gordon operator. The functional derivative is then $S_0' = -K\phi$.

Comment: Tahnks!@Tom Heinzl, I am not clear the calculation involving chain rule of $\frac { \partial  }{ \partial \phi  } \frac { 1 }{ 2 } \phi (\Box +{ m }^{ 2 })\phi$, can you slightly write it out formally, thanks!

Comment: @Tom Heinzl, I seem it as multiply between $\phi$ and $(\Box +{m}^{2})$, so I get:$\frac{1}{2} (\Box +{m}^{2})\phi+\frac{1}{2} \phi(\Box+{m}^{2})$, how the $\frac{1}{2}$ can be canceled?

Comment: @Tom Heinzl,Did you mean "chain rule" as:$\frac { \partial}{\partial\phi}\phi(\Box+{m}^{2})\phi =\frac{ 1}{2}(\Box+{m}^{2})\phi+\frac{1}{2}\phi\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}(\Box+{m}^{2})\phi$, and the latter term is:$\frac {1}{2}\phi\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}(\Box+{m}^{2})\phi=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \phi (\frac { \partial  }{ { \partial  }{ \partial  }^{ \mu  }\phi  } { \partial  }_{ \mu  }{ \partial  }^{ \mu  }\phi \frac { \partial  }{ { \partial  }\phi  } { \partial  }^{ \mu  }\phi +{ m }^{ 2 })$, but I can't get the explicit form of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints to the question (v2):

1. First of all, one should realize the abuse of notation in eq. (6.69) of Ref. 1 where $\phi$ is used in two meanings: both as an external parameter and as internal integration/dummy variable. It is more properly written as
   $$ \widehat {Z}[\phi]~=~\frac{{e}^{iS[\phi]}}{{\cal N}}, \qquad {\cal N}~:=~\int\!{\cal D}\phi~e^{iS[\phi]} .\tag{6.69'}$$
2. Similarly, eq. (6.72) is essentially equivalent to 
   $$ \frac { \delta \widehat { Z } [\phi ] }{ \delta \phi(x)} ~=~\frac{1}{\cal N} \frac {\delta {e}^{iS[\phi]} }{ \delta \phi(x)} 
    ~=~\frac{{e}^{iS[\phi]}}{{\cal N}}\frac{\delta S[\phi ]}{\delta\phi(x) }
   ~=~\widehat { Z } [\phi ]\frac{\delta S[\phi ]}{\delta\phi(x) }.\tag{6.72'} $$
   In the first equality we stress that we shouldn't differentiate the denominator ${\cal N}$ wrt. $\phi(x)$ because the denominator ${\cal N}$ doesn't depend on $\phi(x)$, cf. comment by David Vercauteren.
3. Finally, the [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) $\frac{\delta S[\phi ]}{\delta\phi(x) }$ becomes the [Euler-Lagrange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) expression.

References:

1. L.H. Ryder, QFT; Section 6.4, p. 197.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Qmechenic,but I also have a puzzle about the notion ":" in front of equality（“=”）in 6.69'， what it is mean?

Comment: @alxandernashzhang: The notation $A:=B$ means _$A$ is defined to be equal to $B$._ Similarly, the notation $A=:B$ means _$B$ is defined to be equal to $A$._